# Casting spinners in android

Tags: android, spinner

I'm currently trying out the google's various android examples at http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

BUT I can't seem to get this part to work even though the code is exactly the same as the one provided in the website.

Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

Eclipse keeps saying "Cannot cast from View to Spinner"

Anyone of you guys kno how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Everybody's a noob at some point :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you imported `android.widget.Spinner` and not something else named the same thing? Maybe try the following, just to be sure:

```
android.widget.Spinner s = (android.widget.Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

If it doesn't give you a problem there then odds are high that you have a namespace problem.

Answer (score 1):

That seems odd, are you sure you have imported android.widget.Spinner?
Spinner inherits from View so it should work.

Answer (score 1):

As the others suggest, this may be a namespace problem. I ran into this once when fouling up a generic -- to use your case, I defined a class as taking `Foo<Spinner>` instead of `Foo<A>`, and so `Spinner` was defined as a local name in my namespace. It was only when I renamed the generic to `Foo<A>` that my `Spinner` references resolved.

(in my case, it was `String` rather than `Spinner`, but the pattern should hold)

Answer (score 1):

your spinner variable name should not be same as the class name.